# Is there an activity indicator in Wicket?

Tags: java, android-activity, progress-bar, wicket, wait

I'll make this short:

Is there a way / library in Wicket to show an activity indicator? You know, the spinning thing that moves while the user is waiting for something, or is it just a javascript thing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please don't call that thing a spinner. The term becomes overloaded, and answers become harder to find. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinner_%28computing%29

Comment: (for the record: I call it 'activity indicator'; I don't know if it's an official name). check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582328/spinner-vs-activity-indicator

Comment: Wasn't sure what to call it. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Bozho, funny thing is, I probably wouldn't have found this answer if it wasn't for the term "spinner" :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this is an ajax operation then you can look at the implementations of `IAjaxIndicatorAware`. These implementations will show a 'spinner' while the operation is processing.

e.g. `IndicatingAjaxButton` and `IndicatingAjaxLink`

You could also look at `AjaxIndicatorAppender` and alter it your own needs for non ajax things ?

Comment: Is there any reason to perpetuate the OP's faulty use of the term 'spinner'?

Comment: Wasn't sure what to call it. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Check [here](http://www.ajaxload.info/) to generate your own 'activity indicator'.

Simply show it when busy & hide it afterwards.

Comment: Okay, that generates the Graphic, but I think the question is about wiring it together with a wicket AJAX request

Comment: Yes, the idea was if the activity indicator (not using the word spinner anymore) is possible to create from Wicket, instead of adding custom Javascript. Thanks for the link though. It might come handy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87917

The Javascript and Css must be add  in the renderHEad-Method