# spinner vs activity indicator

Tags: user-interface, web-applications

The question is purely about the naming. Recently I was looking for a spinner (that is, a numеric text box with plus and minus buttons ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinner_%28computing%29))), and too many of the results were actually (ajax) activity indicators.

- is it accepted to call the activity indicator "spinner"
- is it good to do so (subjective). I think this term overloading is making it harder to find the right component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the accepted name for an activity indicator is a Throbber.  I've heard of Numeric UpDowns being called Spinners, because they don't necessarily contain only numbers.