# Spinner component in Wicket?

Tags: wicket, spinner

Where can I find a spinner component for Wicket?, including Maven repo and a source code example?

Comment: Do you mean a spinner or do you mean an activity indicator, if you mean activity indicator this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5582084/569659

Comment: I mean something like JSpinner for Swing: "A single line input field that lets the user select a number or an object value from an ordered sequence. Spinners typically provide a pair of tiny arrow buttons for stepping through the elements of the sequence."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wicketstuff-minis has an implementation of a spinner. There is also a wicketstuff-minis-examples project

The maven repos are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
    <artifactId>minis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.17.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wicketstuff-examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>minis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.17.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let your component implement `IAjaxIndicatorAware` and provide it with the markup ID for your spinner, or use `IndicatingAjaxLink`, `IndicatingAjaxFallbackLink` and `IndicatingAjaxButton`.