# Wicket for the number of copies selection

Tags: java, apache, wicket

[image]

Where I can find a class from Apache Wicket to implement the selection list above? I need the same functionality as in the printer dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This component is called "Spinner".

See the answers of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273860/spinner-component-in-wicket).

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to display it on html? I couldn't find any example.

Comment: There is no Spinner component defined in HTML. It's based on a Textfield and some Javascript-magic for the Up- and Down-arrows. Download the sources provided from the wicketstuff page including the javascript file.

Comment: All the svn links didn't seem to be working. Do you know any download source? Cheers

Comment: Yeah the wicketstuff is more down than anything else, very annoying. You can get all the things with Maven in this repo: [http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/wicketstuff/](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/wicketstuff/)

Comment: I´ve got the javascript and css but I've no idea how to use them with textfield. Is there surely some sort of example right? Or would you be kindly briefly exaplain to me about what needs to be done here?

Comment: I´ve been searching for a related tutorial but there was nothing. It's very annoying.

Comment: Have a look at the examples, maybe this guides you to the right path: [http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/wicketstuff/wicketstuff-minis-examples/](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/wicketstuff/wicketstuff-minis-examples/)